# How can i move my button and placeholder to be responsive?

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4, placeholder

Hello i am currently stuck as my button and place holder image are not responsive i am currently putting inside a form here below u can see my example of the image

[image]

The image are being cut when i start to minimize the screen page to smaller size view

I have use code for as an example to test

I have tested with the class = fluid it seems not working if i try to minize it cut the image

[image]

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <form id="form" class="needs-validation" action="" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="validationName" class="col-2 col-form-label">Name:</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input name="validationName" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationName" placeholder="Company Name" required>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="validationEmail" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-10">
        <input name="text2" type="email" class="form-control" id="validationEmail" placeholder="example1@gmail.com" pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" required>

      </div>
    </div>


   
    <div style=" left: 500px; top: 10px; position: absolute;">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/placeholder-avatar.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="output" width="100" height="100" style="border-radius: 50%;" />
      <br/><br>
      <!-- <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer; padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 1px; position: static; margin-left: 45px; height: 30px;">Select Image</label> -->
    </div>





    <button style="left: 525px; top: 120px; position: absolute;" type="submit" class="submitb btn btn-primary">Submit</button>


  </form>
```

So how can i move the image and button to the left side of the screen if the resolution of the screen got smaller then being cut ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap 4 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images):

> Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with .img-fluid. max-width: 100%; and height: auto; are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.

add class `img-fluid` to your `<img>` tag

```
  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/placeholder-avatar.jpg" id="output" class="img-fluid" width="100" height="100" style="border-radius: 50%;" />
```

Comment: hi i tested with the img-fluid on my image in the flidder is still cut the image if i make the page smaller